# Jquery show/hide tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, onclick, hide, show

Could someone please help me?

Here is my page: http://www.blackstoneparksconservancy.org/donations/

I am having trouble using Jquery, I want another div's content to show when the user clicks "Sustainer" or "One Time".

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: IS your problem with overlapping of those tabs or once you click on them u r not getting desired result!

Comment: I want when people click on either tab, another divs content will show in the black bordered box below.  The overlapping isn't the problem.

Comment: Here the link will helps.... https://jsfiddle.net/Karthik_Dev/g6axy6nt/

Comment: thank you very much